# Обрезается фон при адаптиве

Tags: css3, изображения, адаптивная-верстка

```
._ibg {
  position: relative;
}

._ibg img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main-block__background-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Уже несколько дней не могу найти решение. Вставляю фоновое изображение, вроде все хорошо, растягивается, но при достижении 400пкс, начинает сползать и обрезаться.  Заранее благодарю.

UPD. Обрезается сама обертка, но опять же, не пойму почему. Приложила второй скрин. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы текстовая информация (код например) была текстовой в самом вопросе

Comment: А я теперь не могу исправить свой вопрос. Тогда мне задать его заново?

Comment: Можете, нажмите на [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1371170/edit) под самим вопросом. Пока данный вопрос не закрыт, создавать новый по той же самой теме не нужно

Comment: Спасибо. Исправила.

Comment: Супер, картинки с кодом можно удалять. Они не нужны. От меня вам плюс, за понимание и отзывчивость=)

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, вёрстку и все стили. Можете так же воспользоваться функционалом вставки кода, горячая клавиша Ctrl+M, когда выделена область для ввода сообщения (при написании/редактировании вопроса). Не забудьте залить Ваше изображение на какой-нибудь хостинг картинок, чтобы Вы могли его вставить в вёрстку.